# SQL Queries are taking time

Tags: oracle10g

I need to know that if I am having a set of 1000 queries, and I am executing them in one go. If the particular set of queries taking time, then what can be the possible reason, it's taking time and by what means I can resolve this issue.

Comment: there may be a problem of database locks, which may be acquired during execution of one query and aren't released automatically. just a thought!!

Answer (score 1):

Profile them. All running queries are can be seen by querying `v$session` with your `SID` & `serial#`. Once you have the `SQL_Id`, you can query `v$sql` with the SQL_id to show what query is running.

`v$session` also shows a wealth of other information, including wait states, events which you can go through and figure out what to.

Go through `v$locked_object` to see if there are any objects which are locked, preventing the queries from executing.

Further reading:

- [Tom Kyte talks about Oracle Wait Events](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1154234872764)
- [Oracle Documentation on Tuning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/instance_tune.htm#i14157)

Comment: My answer talks about identifying & profiling the SQL. Use explain plan on the query to find out what part of the query is causing the problem. @user1131913